# Wordpress Insert Parameters In Shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, taxonomy-terms

I work with **several front-end editors only**.
in these cases where the editors are **very different** and are **not flexible!** I use [code snippets](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) to display a piece of information I need in a consistent way everywhere.

it's **so simple** that I feel like no one understands what I'm doing or trying to do. please read carefully and look at the illustrations.

In my case today

I have a taxonomy called **"property_city"** attached to the CTP "property" (nothing extraordinary)

[image]

its interests me because I want to display its terms in this way
**[Parent] -> [Child of parent] -> [Child of parent] -> etc all in hierarchy way**

let's try to post an ad ok?

my apartment is located in **manhattan** so I **selectd manhattan**. by default the parent **New York** are not displayed.

with this **snippet code** it's possible

(/!\ don't be confused, we only use snippet codes no php files or templates to modify. we just inject a snippet./!)

```
function taxonomy_hierarchy() {
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
$return = '';
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'property_city' ); //Put your custom taxonomy term here
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

// this gets the parent of the current post taxonomy
    if ($term->parent != 0) {
        $return .= $term->name. ', ' .get_term( $term->parent, 'property_city' )->name;
    } else {
        $return .= $term->name;
    }
}
return $return;
}
add_shortcode( 'parent-child', 'taxonomy_hierarchy' );
```

Done! **New York**,Manhattan now displayed.

***My question*** is how to make this shortcode **[parent-child]** MORE flexible?
with just output a text (=nolink) **parameter** or output links (=link).

in our example it will look like that

**[parent-child=nolink]** for my loops for e.g.

[image]

**[parent-child=link]** for the posts.

[image]

thanks if you have any idea how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a gander at the [`add_shortcode()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) and you'll see that the callback function is passed three parameters. The most important (and relevant to this) is the first `$atts` parameter.

I would do something like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'parent-child', 'taxonomy_hierarchy' );
function taxonomy_hierarchy( $atts ){
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'link' => true,
        'taxonomy' => 'property_city'
    ), $atts, 'parent-child' );

    global $post;
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );

    /* You can pass conditions here to override
     * the link var based on certain conditions. If
     * it's a single post, current user is editor, etc.
     */

    ob_start();
    foreach( $terms as $term ){
        if( $term->parent != 0 ){
            $parent_term = get_term( $term->parent, $taxonomy );
            echo (filter_var($atts['link'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)) ? sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>, ', esc_url( get_term_link($parent_term) ), $parent_term->name ) : "{$parent_term->name}, " ;
        }

        echo (filter_var($atts['link'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)) ? sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_term_link($term) ), $term->name ) : $term->name ;
    }   

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

This, using the [`shortcode_atts()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/) allows you to set some default parameters for your shortcode. I've also set it so `taxonomy` can be overwritten as well, which makes it much more extensible (for use later, in other projects, etc.)

I've changed the code slightly as well to use [`Output Buffering`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) since it's a bit faster and cleaner when dealing with [Ternary Comparisons](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) and outputs like this compared to string concatenation (imo).

What it does is check to see if the `$link` attribute has been passed before determining to output the linked name, or just the name in plain text, and echoes the result into the output buffer.

This will allow you to get the following results:

```
[parent-child]
  • <a href="#">New York</a>
  • <a href="#">New York</a>, <a href="#">Manhattan</a>

[parent-child link="true"]
  • <a href="#">New York</a>
  • <a href="#">New York</a>, <a href="#">Manhattan</a>

[parent-child link="false"]
  • New York
  • New York, Manhattan

[parent-child link="false" taxonomy="some_other_taxonomy"]
  • Top Level Term
  • Top Level Term, Child Level Term
```

And so on. As I alluded to in the PHP comment, you can override the `$link` boolean at any time before the `foreach` loop, based on whatever conditions you want as well. So you can make the `$link` always return true if `is_single()` is true, or always return false if the current user isn't an editor, or anything else you can think of.

### Documentation & Function Reference:

| Function | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `add_shortcode()` | [Adds a new shortcode.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) |
| `shortcode_atts()` | [Combine user attributes with known attributes and fill in defaults when needed.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/) |
| `ob_start(); ob_get_clean();` | [Output Control, pause script output (besides headers)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) |
| `(condition) ? true : false` | [Shorthand comparison expression to evaluate a result.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) |

Comment: thank you Xhynk for this fantastic explanation
this is an answer beyond my expectations clean and easy to understand code!
I spent 1h testing, in the beginning it didn't want to display the parent terms. So I found that because of  "if ($ term-> parent === 0)" i changed it to "if ($ term-> parent! = 0)" for the moment I can't get [parent-child link = "false"] to work. 
there maybe another little error.

Comment: Oh shoot, sorry about the `===` that was from something I was doing earlier. I've updated that. I've also changed  `$link` part to `$link != false`. You can also put `var_dump( $link )` in there somewhere to make sure it's showing the value you want

Comment: hello, Xhynk, this is another task i tried to separate parent and childs, i failed this task is it possible to request a change to separate parent - child values here? I ask you the question before opening another topic maybe it's better another topic like that I put the link here? what do you think about it

Comment: You're probably better off asking another question since the answer here works for the question above, as it's written and could provide benefit to other users in its current state

Comment: thanks I opened another [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727060/wordpress-improve-shortcode-with-more-parameters)