# Wordpress improve shortcode with more parameters

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, taxonomy

when you are a new designer and start working with several content editors in wordpress, the first thing you realize is that it is not easy to find the functions you want exactly.
plugin editors can't think of everything.. and **especially extract information** to **display them everywhere** in the desired and consistent manner.

that's why wordpress shortcodes exist. but you have to master them.. first! (which is precisely my handicap currently)

Grab your cup of coffee ☕ and admire the detailed visual of **today's issue**

It will be very short and precise,

before starting look at what taxonomies we have in our post..

[image]

my current code allows me to do **figure 1**, as you can see it quickly becomes limited when you try to be .. **more creative**

```
add_shortcode( 'parent-child', 'taxonomy_hierarchy' );
function taxonomy_hierarchy( $atts ){
    // Don't extract, rather parse shortcode params with defaults.
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'link' => 'true',
        'taxonomy' => 'property_city'
    ), $atts, 'parent-child' );

    // Check the $atts parameters and their typecasting.
    //var_dump( $atts );

    global $post;
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $atts['taxonomy'] );

    /* You can pass conditions here to override
     * $link based on certain conditions. If it's
     * a single post, current user is editor, etc.
     */

    ob_start();
    foreach( $terms as $term ){
        if( $term->parent != 0 ){
            $parent_term = get_term( $term->parent, $taxonomy );
            if ($atts['link'] !== 'false') {
                printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>, ', esc_url( get_term_link($parent_term) ), $parent_term->name );
            } else {
                echo $parent_term->name . ', ';
            }
        }

        if ($atts['link'] !== 'false') {
            printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_term_link($term) ), $term->name );
        } else {
            echo $term->name;
        }
    }

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

[image]
in this **figure 1** we don't need to display **"residential"** and **"rental"** it doesn't make sense it's **confusing**. **we don't have** control over this.

but..What if I want to test and accomplish **figure 2**, **figure 3** and **figure 4**

[image]

**You** : but there are already shortcodes what is it???

yes, don't worry, I took care **to simulate a logic of things** inside shortcodes, **maybe that's not exactly how it's going to be. or how things work ..**

I prefer to remain cautious and wait for your opinion or solution.

if logic allows, we need to separate the **parent** and **childs** values ​​and paste them back as we want
like a puzzle

Something Like

**↑[taxonomy-parent = "name_of_my_taxonomy"]**

**↓[taxonomy-child = "name_of_my_taxonomy"]**

or simply reverse in some cases

**←[child-parent]** (manhattan, new york)

**→[parend-child]** (new york, manhattan)

note that I used [[acf field "name field here"]](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/shortcode/) to invoke a price value, if it is possible to fit it **inside** our combination or leave it like that?

**final word:** you can tell I spent **some time** working out and thinking about this, if only coding was that easy for me I would have done even better. for now that's all I need more **flexibility** to display information in different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using an `array()` instead to store the `$parent` if it exists, and then the `$child` which should exist. This would give you the benefit of being able to use [`array_reverse()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) to flip the order of the terms based on a parameter saying whether you want the parent or the child first. This gives you the added benefit of being able to convert the array to a string with the [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function, which you can pass a `$glue` argument to, to determine whether you want them separated by a space, comma + space, hyphen, slash, etc.

```
add_shortcode( 'parent-child', 'taxonomy_hierarchy' );
function taxonomy_hierarchy( $atts ){
    // Don't extract, rather parse shortcode params with defaults.
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'link'     => 'true',
        'glue'     => ', ',
        'taxonomy' => 'property_city',
        'first'    => 'parent',
    ), $atts, 'parent-child' );

    // Check the $atts parameters and their typecasting.
    //var_dump( $atts );

    global $post;
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $atts['taxonomy'] );

    /* You can pass conditions here to override
     * $link based on certain conditions. If it's
     * a single post, current user is editor, etc.
     */

    $array = array();
    foreach( $terms as $term ){
        if( $term->parent != 0 ){
            $parent_term = get_term( $term->parent, $taxonomy );
            if ($atts['link'] !== 'false') {
                $array[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_term_link($parent_term) ), $parent_term->name );
            } else {
                $array[] = $parent_term->name;
            }
        }

        if( $atts['link'] !== 'false' ){
            $array = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_term_link($term) ), $term->name );
        } else {
            $array = $term->name;
        }
    }

    if( $atts['first'] != 'parent' ){
        $array = array_reverse( $array );
    }

    return implode($glue, $array);
}
```

Doing this should give you the ability to put out shortcodes like:

```
[parent-child first="child" glue=" - "]  // Child - Parent
[parent-child glue="/"]  // Parent/Child
```

---

#### Documentation & Function Reference

| Function | Linked Description |
| --- | --- |
| `array_reverse()` | [Return an array with elements in reverse order](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) |
| `implode()` | [Join array elements with a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) |

Comment: hello Xlink, I think there is a typo I have an **error implode () invalid arguments passed** but thinking about where the error is, I ended up understanding that maybe it necessary to split the code into several shortcodes ! look at my response to the pos

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a **solution** but in this case it is no longer a shortcode with parameters.
it's become a **bunch of shortcodes** with a parameters, at least we have more **flexibility** now.

I simply cut the code into **3 parts**
if you are not afraid to see  very long complicated shortcodes. it's a solution that will help.

but I'm not sure if this is the **best practice**.

[image]

> output taxonomy parent, child

```
/*output taxonomy parent, child*/

add_shortcode( 'parent-child', 'taxonomy_hierarchy' );
function taxonomy_hierarchy( $atts ){

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'link' => 'true',
        'taxonomy' => 'property_city' // my default taxonomy 
    ), $atts, 'parent-child' );

    global $post;
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $atts['taxonomy'] );

    ob_start();
    foreach( $terms as $term ){
        if( $term->parent != 0 ){
            $parent_term = get_term( $term->parent, $taxonomy );
            if ($atts['link'] !== 'false') {
                printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>, ', esc_url( get_term_link($parent_term) ), $parent_term->name );
            } else {
                echo $parent_term->name . ', ';
            }
        }

        if ($atts['link'] !== 'false') {
            printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_term_link($term) ), $term->name );
        } else {
            echo $term->name;
        }
    }

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

> output only taxonomy parent

```
/*output only taxonomy parent*/

add_shortcode( 'parent', 'taxonomy_parent' );
function taxonomy_parent( $atts ){
  
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'link' => 'true',
        'taxonomy' => 'property_city' // my default taxonomy 
    ), $atts, 'parent' );

    global $post;
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $atts['taxonomy'] );

    ob_start();
    foreach( $terms as $term ){
        if( $term->parent != 0 ){
            $parent_term = get_term( $term->parent, $taxonomy );
            if ($atts['link'] !== 'false') {
                printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_term_link($parent_term) ), $parent_term->name );
            } else {
                echo $parent_term->name;
            }
        }      
    }

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

> output only taxonomy child

```
/*output only taxonomy child*/

add_shortcode( 'child', 'taxonomy_child' );
function taxonomy_child( $atts ){
  
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'link' => 'true',
        'taxonomy' => 'property_city' // my default taxonomy 
    ), $atts, 'child' );

    global $post;
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $atts['taxonomy'] );

    ob_start();
    foreach( $terms as $term ){
        if ($atts['link'] !== 'false') {
            printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_term_link($term) ), $term->name );
        } else {
            echo $term->name;
        }
    }

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

[image]

[image]